Pouring self-leveling cement over old mosaic tile mesh underlayment
My house build in the 1960s has a bathroom that appears to have been once tiled with those mosaic tiles that contained a mesh backing. I'm hoping to tile over the current thinset and remnants of the mesh, but not sure if it will weaken my bond or not. Given the age, I'm also not sure if it might have contained asbestos. Would I be better off putting another layer of new thinset over it first before my primer and Mapei self leveling compound, or can I just prime it directly and lay the compound over it? Or do I really need to chisel it out?
(And to head off any concerns, I do realize that I'd need to remove any loose debris at the bare minimum)


You can pour your self leveler right over that.
I am assuming that you are doing the bath floor and not the shower floor, that needs to have a slope toward the drain.

Does the OP even really need self-leveler here, unless they just want to flatten the area?

@Huesmann, good point. If large format , non rectified tiles are going down a 3/8 notched trowel on the thinset would work well..
